# can't search fetched data from html table

Tags: javascript, html

I have some code (as below) HTML and JavaScript . Actually, I've already fetched some of data from a covid-19 API and also i kept those information on HTML table .
So, now i wanna search info from the HTML table with country name. But, I couldn't that. So, please some one help me to solve this problem .

```js
fetch('https://api.covid19api.com/summary')
 .then(response => response.json())
 .then(data => {
    var tbody = document.querySelector('#tbody');
   tbody.innerHTML = `
   <tr>
<td>${data.Global.NewConfirmed}</td>
<td>${data.Global.TotalConfirmed}</td>
<td>${data.Global.TotalDeaths}</td>
<td>${data.Global.TotalRecovered}</td>
   </tr>
   `

   var all_covid_data = document.querySelector('#all_covid_data')
    var countries = data.Countries ;


      for(var i =1;i<countries.length ; i++){

        all_covid_data.innerHTML += `   <tr>
        <td class='bg-primary text-light '>${countries[i].Country}</td>
        <td>${countries[i].NewConfirmed}</td>
        <td>${countries[i].NewDeaths}</td>
        <td>${countries[i].NewRecovered}</td>
        <td>${countries[i].TotalConfirmed }</td>
        <td>${countries[i].TotalRecovered}</td>
        <td>${countries[i].TotalDeaths}</td>
           </tr>`;


  }
 })
 .catch(err => console.log(err))


 // searching or filtering data from table
var tableRow = document.getElementById('all_covid_data');
var inputField = document.getElementById('searchBox');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>Covid-19 Info</title>

</head>
<body>


    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2"></div>
            <div class="col-md-8 py-3">
                <h2 class="text-uppercase text-center">Covid-19 Informations</h2>
                <hr style="width: 110px; text-align: center; border-width: 3px; border-color:#17A2B8">

                <table class="table">
                    <thead class="bg-info text-light">
                     <tr>
                         <th>NewConfirmed</th>
                         <th>TotalCases</th>
                         <th>TotalDeaths</th>
                         <th>TotalRecovered</th>
                     </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody class="bg-dark text-light" id='tbody'>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2"></div>
        </div>




        <section id="countries_data" class="py-4">
          <div class="row">
           <div class="col-12">
            <div class="d-flex">
                <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Search here" id="searchBox"  class="form-control">
                <button class="btn ml-2 btn-info">Search</button>
            </div>
           </div>
          </div>

         <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-bordered table-striped  my-4 table-hover">
            <thead class="bg-info text-light">
              <tr>
                <th>Countries</th>
                <th>NewConfirmed</th>
                <th>NewDeaths</th>
                <th>NewRecovered</th>
                <th>TotalConfirmed</th>
                <th>TotalRecovered</th>
                <th>TotalDeaths</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id='all_covid_data'>

            </tbody>
          </table>
         </div>
        </section>
    </div>




<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Im missing an attempt on coding the search function, Did you make an attempt but left it out of the provided code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You need to show at least some effort in solving the problem in the code. As @RamondeVries said, there is no code for the search function.

Comment: You are fetching data from an API and you have it in Javascript. Why are you looking it from the HTML codes. Store and search it on Javascript and when somebody search filter the javascript array and print it again to the HTML table.

Answer (score 0):

- Create separate methods, one to fetch data from API & another to populate the table.
- Simply use `filter()` method to filter Country by name and re-use the `populateTable()` method.
- Start the `for` loop from `0`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var summary;

  fetch('https://api.covid19api.com/summary')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      summary = data;
      populateTable(data);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))

  function populateTable(data) {
    var tbody = document.querySelector('#tbody');
    tbody.innerHTML = `
   <tr>
<td>${data.Global.NewConfirmed}</td>
<td>${data.Global.TotalConfirmed}</td>
<td>${data.Global.TotalDeaths}</td>
<td>${data.Global.TotalRecovered}</td>
   </tr>
   `;
    var countries = data.Countries;
    let content = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
      content += `<tr>
        <td class='bg-primary text-light '>${countries[i].Country}</td>
        <td>${countries[i].NewConfirmed}</td>
        <td>${countries[i].NewDeaths}</td>
        <td>${countries[i].NewRecovered}</td>
        <td>${countries[i].TotalConfirmed }</td>
        <td>${countries[i].TotalRecovered}</td>
        <td>${countries[i].TotalDeaths}</td>
           </tr>`;
    }
    $('#all_covid_data').html(content);
  }

  // searching or filtering data from table
  var tableRow = document.getElementById('all_covid_data');
  var inputField = document.getElementById('searchBox');

  $("#search_btn").click(() => {
    var filteredData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(summary));
    filteredData.Countries = filteredData.Countries.filter(c => c.Country.toLowerCase().includes(inputField.value.toLowerCase()));
    if (filteredData.Countries.length > 0) {
      $('#all_covid_data').html('');
      populateTable(filteredData);
    } else {
      alert('Country not found');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <title>Covid-19 Info</title>

</head>

<body>


  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2"></div>
      <div class="col-md-8 py-3">
        <h2 class="text-uppercase text-center">Covid-19 Informations</h2>
        <hr style="width: 110px; text-align: center; border-width: 3px; border-color:#17A2B8">

        <table class="table">
          <thead class="bg-info text-light">
            <tr>
              <th>NewConfirmed</th>
              <th>TotalCases</th>
              <th>TotalDeaths</th>
              <th>TotalRecovered</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody class="bg-dark text-light" id='tbody'>

          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    </div>




    <section id="countries_data" class="py-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="d-flex">
            <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Search here" id="searchBox" class="form-control">
            <button class="btn ml-2 btn-info" id="search_btn">Search</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped  my-4 table-hover">
          <thead class="bg-info text-light">
            <tr>
              <th>Countries</th>
              <th>NewConfirmed</th>
              <th>NewDeaths</th>
              <th>NewRecovered</th>
              <th>TotalConfirmed</th>
              <th>TotalRecovered</th>
              <th>TotalDeaths</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody id='all_covid_data'>

          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>




  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Popper JS -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much . But how can i do this using vanila JavaScript ?

Comment: @Shakil if you understand the logic written in JQuery & JS-ES6, you can easily write your code in Vanilla JS. Just a matter of syntax changes right !?

Comment: again thank you . Yeh, rght you are . actually i successfully done the work .

Comment: I'm glad my answer helped you! Please upvote it for the amount of effort given & consider marking it as correct so it can help other people checking this question also! :)